Why is my springboot auth application not working on phone?
Currently, I am trying to build a simple website using spring boot and is currently hosted on AWS EC2 free tier connection using the Elastic Beanstalk application and the authentication code showed below works perfectly fine with dekstop but when I try logging in through my phone, it just reloads the page and the navbar which is supposed to change based on if user exists or not never changes. Why does this keep happening?
Sign In mapping:
@PostMapping("/signin")
    public String handleSignIn(
            @RequestParam String email,
            @RequestParam String password,
            HttpSession session,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            Model model,
            HttpServletResponse response
    ) {
        var user = userService.findUserByEmail(email);

        if(user.isPresent() && user.get().getPassword().equals(password)) {
            String tokenValue = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            System.out.println("Saving cookie" + tokenValue);

            Cookie securityCookie = new Cookie("authToken", tokenValue);
            securityCookie.setHttpOnly(false);
            securityCookie.setSecure(true);
            securityCookie.setPath("/");

            userService.setToken(user.get(), tokenValue);

            response.addCookie(securityCookie);
            

            model.addAttribute("message", "Login Successful");
            return "redirect:/dashboard";
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Invalid email or password");
            return "signin";
        }
    }

Dashboard show mapping:
@GetMapping("/dashboard")
    public String showDashboard(HttpSession session, Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<EventPricing> pricings = eventPricingService.findAllEventPricing();
        model.addAttribute("pricings", pricings);
        
        List<Event> events = eventService.findAllEvents();
        for (int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++) {
            if (events.get(i).getPublished() == 0) {
                events.remove(i);
                i = i - 1;
            } else {
                if(events.get(i).getParticipationAllowed() == 1)
                {
                    eventService.updatePartiStatusChecker(events.get(i));
                    
                }
            }
        }
        for (Event event: events) {
            List<EventPricing> eventPricings = eventPricingService.findEventPricingsByEventId(event.getEventId());
            for (EventPricing pricing : eventPricings) {
                eventPricingService.resetStatus(pricing);
            }
        }

        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        String authToken = null;
        if(cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if("authToken".equals(cookie.getName())) {
                    authToken = cookie.getValue();
                    System.out.println("Found cookie " + authToken);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(authToken != null && userService.validateToken(authToken)) {
            var user = userService.getUserByToken(authToken);
            model.addAttribute("loggedInUser", user);
            System.out.println("Added to model " + user.get().getFullName());
        }

        model.addAttribute("events", events);
        return "dashboard";

//        if(loggedInUser != null) {
//            model.addAttribute("userEmail", loggedInUser.getEmail());
//            model.addAttribute("userName", loggedInUser.getFullName());
//            return "dashboard";
//        }
    }

Also for some reason the event and event pricing model attributes that are being set show up, its just the loggedInUser attribute not working on phone. Thanks for the help!
I did try changing from session attributes so basically just HttpSession.setAttribute and get attribute, which was the first thing that I tried to do, which had the same problem(worked on dekstop but not on phone), so I found another stack overflow issue with the same problem but with cookies, so I tried using cookies instead, however, now the cookies also don't seem to work. I have no idea where to go from here.
